# Is there a way of merging imported functions into a single page of code?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to use cython to turn a script into an exe file, but it's a bit awkward in that it doesn't work with imports, so I just spent the last 3 hours writing a script that'll merge all my code into one file. It uses `inspect.getsourcelines(function)` to read functions so that I don't need to actually parse the files as text, then it trims out most of the comments and spaces. [Here's](https://pastebin.com/RiXNFnjK) the current result with functions gathered from about 10 files.

I sent to a friend to test it out, and he said it gave an ImportError that PIL wasn't installed. It appears that even as an exe file, the script looks to the Python directory and won't work without the modules installed.

I'm using PIL, numpy and scipy, and especially with numpy, it's not a simple module, and I'll probably have a lot of trouble merging in the code. Is there existing code that would be able to recursively go through all the functions and merge them onto the same page? It's an unusual request but I'm assuming it's not the first time it's been attempted.

The efficiency of cython compared to programs like py2exe seems really good (the exe file is 880kb as opposed to over 100mb), so I would like to eventually get it working if possible.

Comment: Why do you want to make an .exe file in the first place?  Why not just let Python be Python, and if you want to use Cython for performance reasons, package that code as a shared library, as is conventional?

Comment: Mainly so that your average person who's never used python doesn't need to pip install a ton of stuff just to get the script running haha (it took me quite a while to get scipy up and running). It got quite a bit of interest on reddit so I'd like to make it easy to run :)

Comment: If the user doesn't `pip install scipy` how are they going to get scipy?  I mean it has a lot of code not only written in Python but also C and Fortran.  You can't expect to bundle all of it into an .exe...can  you?

Comment: I'm aiming for a standalone exe that the user can double click to generate the images, and pyinstaller is quite heavy handed with the amount of modules it includes. I'm only using the `zoom` and `gaussian_filter` functions from `scipy.ndimage`, so I'd have thought it'd not be too much to bundle within the exe (certainly less than the 250mb of code that pyinstaller collects), I wasn't aware it had parts written in other languages though, that'll probably make things a bit too awkward to do manually :P

Comment: I guess if I have no luck with anything, I can live with the pyinstaller folder option and having shortcuts to it, it's just a little annoying after spending so many hours getting the C compiling working to not use it.